# Hyperledger fabric previous hash knowing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

```
{
  "_id": "2018-06-29 06:30:39.595259865 +0000 UTC m=+146426.593768305",
  "_rev": "1-2811e772710ee53a3449ddf1907fb767",
  "AcquiringDivision": "Sony",
  "EndDate": "20-05-2019",
  "Excl": "yes",
   "Owner": "MCU",
  "ProductID": "1011",
  "~version": "2:0"
}
```

These is my couch db instance where i can see the json data. But I am unable to see the hash of the previous data

2)when the block is getting incremented the  "~version": "2:0"  is being incremented  such as  ("~version": "3:0") what is ("~version":) in my couchdb in block chain

Answer (score 0):

According to me, couchDB instance is only the current state of database, you won't see the hash of the block or anything like that.
Fields "_rev", "_id" and "~version" are for internal use, "_rev" is the revision_ID.(http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/documents.html).

About the "~version" field, I guess that is the count of versions of this document. If you change it ten times, you'll get "~version" : "10:0"... Well, I'm not pretty sure about that.